# Angular 2: Running HTTP call on interval

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a service that calls my API like this:

```
return this._http
        .post(apiUrl + 'Controller/Action', params, {withCredentials: true, headers: this.headers})
        .timeoutWith(8000, Observable.defer(() => Observable.throw(this._feedbackService.timeout())))
        .map((response: Response) => response.json().data);
```

And I call that function from my component like this:

```
this._mySub = this._myService.getSomething()
                        .subscribe(
                            response => this._listOfSomething = response,
                            error => this._loggerService.log(2, "warn", "Error bla bla")
                        );
```

How do I run that HTTP call on an interval?

I tried this:

```
this._mySub = this._myService.getSomething()
                        .interval(15000)
                        .startWith(0)
                        .subscribe(
                            response => this._listOfSomething = response,
                            error => this._loggerService.log(2, "warn", "Error bla bla")
                        );
```

But that says:

> Property 'interval' does not exist on type 'Observable< any >'

I kind of got it working like this:

```
Observable.interval(15000).subscribe(() => {
    this.refreshList();
});

refreshList() {

this._mySub = this._myService.getSomething()
                        .subscribe(
                            response => this._listOfSomething = response,
                            error => this._loggerService.log(2, "warn", "Error bla bla")
                        );

}
```

But that seems to fire the HTTP call on almost random times and it feels wrong to set it up that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
let intervalId = setInterval(() => {
   this.updateData();
}, 15000);

updateData(){
  this._mySub = this._myService.getSomething()
                          .subscribe(
                              response => this._listOfSomething = response,
                              error => this._loggerService.log(2, "warn",   "Error bla bla")
                          );
}
```

Good practice is to clear interval when is no needed. You should place your interval in `ngOnInit()` and clear it in `ngOnDestroy()`. Because if you will put it in constructor it will keep updating even when you will switch components (go to another subpage on website).

EDIT. You can clear interval using `clearInterval(intervalId)`.

Comment: That does work better. Thank you. The only "downside" is that I have to manually call `this.updateData()` before setting up the interval, instead of using something more fancy like the `startWith(0)` thing.